# Angular4: handle browser refresh/close event

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular4 application I want to handle browser refresh event. On refresh I want to pop up confirmation alert, once press OK wanna do some actions (call some api calls). I tried below.

```
    // imports'

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      @HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"]) unloadHandler(event: Event) {
        console.log("Processing beforeunload...");
        event.returnValue = true;
      }

      constructor() {
      }

    }
```

Now I can below on pressing F5 on keyboard. But I want to show confirm alert and perform some actions on pressing OK button.

[image]

I want to pop up custom dialog asking something(eg: 'This will release locks of each and every booking you opened. Do you want to proceed?') from the user, once the user clicks on OK button want to call some api calls.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Showing the 'Changes you made may not be saved' dialog is the only action permitted by web browsers in this scenario, so doing any further actions is not possible.

With Internet Explorer, you can set `event.returnValue` to a string value and that string will be displayed to the user to encourage them not to reload/leave, but Chrome ignores that and always displays the same message.

Comment: is there any way to handle `reload` and `cancel`events in javascript ?

Comment: That's really a different question - it's worth posting a new question for that. But, I don't believe so... @k11k2